# apache tomcat 8009 port in use

Tags: java, windows, tomcat

When i Start tomcat on eclipse i got this message:

Port 8009 required by Tomcat v6.0 Server at localhost is already in use. The server may already be running in another process, or a system process may be using the port. To start this server you will need to stop the other process or change the port number(s).

when i start tomcat manually it gives me this exceptions track:

```
C:\apache-tomcat-6\bin>catalina.bat run
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\apache-tomcat-6"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\apache-tomcat-6"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\apache-tomcat-6\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\apache-tomcat-6\bin\bootstrap.jar"
Dec 14, 2011 11:32:17 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.1.22.
Dec 14, 2011 11:32:17 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: APR capabilities: IPv6 [false], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], r
andom [true].
Dec 14, 2011 11:32:20 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Dec 14, 2011 11:32:20 AM org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProtocol init
SEVERE: Error initializing endpoint
java.lang.Exception: Socket bind failed: [730048] Only one usage of each socket
address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint.init(AprEndpoint.java:649)
        at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProtocol.init(AjpAprProtocol.java:160)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initialize(Connector.java:104
9)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initialize(StandardService.j
ava:703)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initialize(StandardServer.jav
a:838)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:538)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:562)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:261)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
Dec 14, 2011 11:32:20 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService initialize
SEVERE: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[AJP/1.3-8009]]
LifecycleException:  Protocol handler initialization failed: java.lang.Exception
: Socket bind failed: [730048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/n
etwork address/port) is normally permitted.
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initialize(Connector.java:105
1)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initialize(StandardService.j
ava:703)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initialize(StandardServer.jav
a:838)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:538)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:562)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:261)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
Dec 14, 2011 11:32:20 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 5684 ms
Dec 14, 2011 11:32:21 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Dec 14, 2011 11:32:21 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.35
Dec 14, 2011 11:32:21 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor

INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor host-manager.xml
Dec 14, 2011 11:32:23 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor

INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor manager.xml
Dec 14, 2011 11:32:23 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory docs
Dec 14, 2011 11:32:23 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory examples
Dec 14, 2011 11:32:24 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory ROOT
Dec 14, 2011 11:32:24 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Dec 14, 2011 11:32:24 AM org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProtocol start
SEVERE: Error starting endpoint
java.lang.Exception: Socket bind failed: [730048] Only one usage of each socket
address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint.init(AprEndpoint.java:649)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint.start(AprEndpoint.java:766)
        at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProtocol.start(AjpAprProtocol.java:188)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.start(Connector.java:1122)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:5
40)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754
)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Dec 14, 2011 11:32:24 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
SEVERE: Failed to start connector [Connector[AJP/1.3-8009]]
LifecycleException:  service.getName(): "Catalina";  Protocol handler start fail
ed: java.lang.Exception: Socket bind failed: [730048] Only one usage of each soc
ket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.start(Connector.java:1129)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:5
40)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754
)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Dec 14, 2011 11:32:24 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 3966 ms
Dec 14, 2011 11:33:25 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Dec 14, 2011 11:33:25 AM org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-8009
Dec 14, 2011 11:33:26 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stop
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Dec 14, 2011 11:33:26 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol destroy
INFO: Stopping Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Dec 14, 2011 11:33:26 AM org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProtocol destroy
INFO: Stopping Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-8009
Terminate batch job (Y/N)? y

C:\apache-tomcat-6\bin>
```

How can fix it? Another tomcat is not running, i checked with localhost:8080.  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Check with `netstat -ntlp | grep :8009` to see what process is using 8009 already.

Comment: 'grep' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. I use windows. Is it in windows?

Comment: @elbek check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5310945/deployment-errorstarting-of-tomcat-failed-the-server-port-8080-is-already-in-u/5310993#5310993)

Comment: pardon me, I hadn't noticed it was windows.  I do not know what a grep equiv. is on windows.  I believe netstat behaves similarly though, try my command without `| grep :8009`

Comment: grep isn't there for windows so OP was facing that error, otherwise you are correct +1

Comment: The roughly equivalent inline search command for windows is `| find ":8009"`

Answer (score 11):

Kill the process first. Then check your %TOMCAT_HOME%/conf/server.xml file. You should replace **port="8009"** with **port="8010"**.

Answer (score 4):

double check by running `ps -ef | grep tomcat` to `kill -9` the process or from your task manager if there is any java process running to terminate it. Most likely your previous tomcat startup session wasn't ended normally.

Answer (score 3):

**For Ubuntu/Linux**

Step 1: Find the process id that is using the port 8009

```
netstat -lnp | grep 8009
or
ps -aef | grep tomcat
```

Step 2: Kill the process using process id in above result

```
kill -9 process_id
```

**For Windows**

Step 1: Find the process id

```
netstat -ano | findstr 8009
```

Step 2: Open command prompt as administrator and kill the process

```
taskkill /F /pid process_id_from_step_1
```

**Changing Port Number**

In you wan to run two Apache tomcat in parallel then change the conflicting port number in Eclipse server overview.

1. Open `Eclipse`
2. Go to `Servers panel`

[image: Eclipse Servers Panel]

3. Double click the configured server name to open `Overview` window
4. Open the `Ports`tab. You will get the following:

   - `Tomcat adminport`
   - `HTTP/1.1`
   - `AJP/1.3`

[image: Eclipse Tomcat Server Overview]

5. Change conflicting port number of `AJP/1.3` (e.g. to `9009`)
6. You might have to also change the port of `Tomcat admin port` (e.g. to `9005`) and of `HTTP/1.1` (e.g. to `9090`).
7. Save it (ctrl+s) and start your server.

Comment: Very thorough solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your port 8009 is already in use. It can be another tomcat or something different.
You should manually kill any tomcat process.
EDIT: assuming you are on Windows platform, kill all javaw.exe process using CTRL-ALT-Suppr

Answer (score -1):

check the file `server.xml` in folder `\apache-tomcat-6.0.32\conf`
the `port address` will be mentioned, if it is `8080`, try changing it to `8081` and start the server and call `localhost:8081`

in `server.xml` it will be like below:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" />
```

Comment: port number is 8009 not 8080, 8080 is free

Comment: check with HTTP protocol like in my answer, normaly in tomcat 8009 will be used for AJP protocol.

Comment: you can even change this port and test. if the server is starting.

Comment: I changed to 8011 and it worked with loclahost:8080 when i start by command line, but i does not work with eclipse