# unable to access Pentaho home

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I have started the Pentaho BI server and the response I get is that Tomcat server has been started.

But while logging into http://localhost:8080/pentaho.

It is prompting for password. As per the documentation/web search I have tried with admin/admin, admin/password, admin/pentaho.

None of them is working. Any guesses ?

When I start the BI server, I get the response as :

```
01HW993798:pentaho-server tcssig$ ./start-pentaho.sh
WARNING: Using java from path
DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME=
DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA=java
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /Users/tcssig/Downloads/pentaho-server/tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /Users/tcssig/Downloads/pentaho-server/tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /Users/tcssig/Downloads/pentaho-server/tomcat/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home
Using CLASSPATH:       /Users/tcssig/Downloads/pentaho-server/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/Users/tcssig/Downloads/pentaho-server/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Tomcat started.
```

Pentaho.log file is as below.

```
2016-11-30 16:36:32,907 INFO  [org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.status.PeriodicStatusLogger] Caution, the system is initializing. Do not shut down or restart the system at this time.
2016-11-30 16:36:33,759 INFO  [org.pentaho.platform.osgi.OSGIBoot] Checking to see if org.pentaho.clean.karaf.cache is enabled
2016-11-30 16:36:33,993 INFO  [org.pentaho.platform.osgi.KarafInstance] 
*******************************************************************************
*** Karaf Instance Number: 1 at /Users/tcssig/Downloads/pentaho-server/pent ***
***   aho-solutions/system/karaf/caches/default/data-1                      ***
*** Karaf Port:8802                                                         ***
*** OSGI Service Port:9051                                                  ***
*** JMX RMI Registry Port:11099                                             ***
*** RMI Server Port:44445                                                   ***
*******************************************************************************
2016-11-30 16:37:02,914 INFO  [org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.status.PeriodicStatusLogger] Caution, the system is initializing. Do not shut down or restart the system at this time.
2016-11-30 16:37:22,379 INFO  [org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.status.PeriodicStatusLogger] The system has finished initializing.
2016-11-30 16:37:26,177 INFO  [org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.status.PeriodicStatusLogger] The system has finished initializing.
2016-11-30 16:37:27,350 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.util.logging.Logger] Error: Pentaho
2016-11-30 16:37:27,351 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.util.logging.Logger] misc-org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem: PentahoSystem.ERROR_0015 - Error while trying to execute shutdown sequence for org.pentaho.platform.plugin.services.pluginmgr.PluginAdapter
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Service already unregistered.
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl.unregister(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:124)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.objfac.OSGIRuntimeObjectFactory$OSGIPentahoObjectRegistration.remove(OSGIRuntimeObjectFactory.java:178)
    at org.pentaho.platform.plugin.services.pluginmgr.PentahoSystemPluginManager.unloadPlugins(PentahoSystemPluginManager.java:225)
    at org.pentaho.platform.plugin.services.pluginmgr.PentahoSystemPluginManager.unloadAllPlugins(PentahoSystemPluginManager.java:917)
    at org.pentaho.platform.plugin.services.pluginmgr.PluginAdapter.shutdown(PluginAdapter.java:47)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.shutdown(PentahoSystem.java:1071)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.context.SolutionContextListener.contextDestroyed(SolutionContextListener.java:282)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4900)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5537)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:221)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1423)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1412)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-11-30 16:37:27,354 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.util.logging.Logger] Error end:
2016-11-30 16:37:27,356 INFO  [org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.status.PeriodicStatusLogger] The system has finished initializing.
2016-11-30 16:37:27,356 WARN  [org.pentaho.platform.web.http.context.PentahoSolutionSpringApplicationContext] Exception thrown from ApplicationListener handling ContextClosedEvent
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Service already unregistered.
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl.unregister(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:124)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.objfac.OSGIRuntimeObjectFactory$OSGIPentahoObjectRegistration.remove(OSGIRuntimeObjectFactory.java:178)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.objfac.spring.PublishedBeanRegistry$1.onApplicationEvent(PublishedBeanRegistry.java:125)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:166)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster$1.run(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:133)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:382)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:336)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:989)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:581)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4900)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5537)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:221)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1423)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1412)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: try login as evaluator. check log in ../biserver-ce/tomcat/logs/pentaho.log

Comment: When I try to login with user ID and password as evaluator, it doesnt go through. Also, the Pentaho.log is message is as below.

Pentaho.log details I have updated in the question.

Comment: might be some problem with package.
if you have just started working with pentaho then i will suggest download it again and start working.

Comment: Hi guys, it was a port issue and got resolved by changing port 8005 to 9005 and port 8009 to 9090 in Server.xml file

Thanks for all your suggestions !

Comment: You are welcome to wrap it up as an answer to help future readers.

Comment: @KamilG. took help from another Stack post.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8509125/apache-tomcat-8009-port-in-use

Answer (score 0):

Try Changing the AJP and Http port numbers in tomcat/conf/server.xml

Comment: (This post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer, or just post it as a comment to the question).