# Tomcat v7.0 Server setup for ports 8086 and 8009

Tags: java, eclipse, installation, port, tomcat7

I am new in java programming. I have write a small web program using struts. I ve already install apche tomcat 7 server. I configure this server to my project. Tomcat server error showing When I run this program. The error is

Starting tomcat v7.0 server at localhost encountered a problem

Several ports (8086, 8009) required by Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost are already in use. The server may already be running in another process, or a system process may be using the port. To start this server you will need to stop the other process or change the port number(s)

Comment: kill the process named javaw.exe

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You [need to find out which process are running over that port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5310945/deployment-errorstarting-of-tomcat-failed-the-server-port-8080-is-already-in-u/5310993#5310993) and if it is not needed you can kill them

or you can change your tomcat's configuration to start the Tomcat instance on another port

for this you need to edit your `server.xml` file located at `TOMCAT_DIR/conf/`

Answer (score 3):

how to solve this Port 8080 required by Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost is already in use. The server may already be running in another process, or a system process may be using the port. To start this server you will need to stop the other process or change the port number(s).

Answer (score 1):

You can [change](http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/how-to-change-tomcat-default-port/) your tomcat ports

Comment: thank narek  , how can i change my port. can u give detail explanation?

Comment: the link on word 'change' was not helpful?

Answer (score 0):

you can change the port details in `{TOMCAT_HOME}\conf\server.xml`

Answer (score 0):

> You've another instance of Server already running. You can confirm this by going to `http://localhost:8080` in your webbrowser and check if you get the specific 404 error page and  Tomcat default home page. Both are equally valid evidence that Tomcat runs fine.
>
> You need to shutdown it.
>
> Open the task manager and kill all java and/or javaw processes.
>   Now open your project and run your application.
>   Open Window -> Preferences -> Server
>
> If Tomcat is not installed go through these steps otherwise skip step

1. In “Servers” area, right click -> New -> Server.
2. You will find Tomcat vx.x Server under “Apache” folder as shown
   below.
3. Select “Tomcat v6.0 Server” and click Next.
4. Select the Tomcat Root folder which has bin folder and click Next.
5. There are no resources to be configured and hence click Finish.
6. The configured Apache Tomcat Server will be displayed in the
   “Servers” view.

> If Tomcat is already installed then go through these steps:

1. In "Server" area, right click -> Add and Remove...
2. Under this, the project need to be configured add the project from
   "Available:" box to "Configured:"
3. Click finish to run the server.