# running 2 tomcat instances on the same ios

Tags: tomcat, windows-7, tomcat7

I would like to run 2 tomcat instances on the same Windows.

So I took the following steps:

1. Downloaded tomcat to folder tomcat1
2. Created a new folder: tomcat2
3. Copied conf folder from tomcat1 to tomcat2
4. Created empty folders: logs, temp,work
5. Created a folder bin and inside I put 2 commands:

startup.bat

```
set CATALINA_BASE=C:\Programs\apache2
set CATALINA_HOME=C:\Programs\apache1
C:\Programs\apache1\bin\startup.bat
```

shutdown.bat

```
set CATALINA_BASE=C:\Programs\apache2
set CATALINA_HOME=C:\Programs\apache1
C:\Programs\apache1\bin\shutdown.bat
```

I also changed the following in **server.xml of apache2** to be:

```
<Server port="8006" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
<Connector port="8081" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
               connectionTimeout="20000" 
               redirectPort="8444" />
<Connector port="8010" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8444" />
```

While in **apache1** it is:

```
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
 <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
               connectionTimeout="20000" 
               redirectPort="8443" />
 <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
```

When I run startup.bat from apache1, although in its server.xml it is configured to be port 8080, it occupies port 8081. This way when I want to run startup.bat from apache2 - the port is busy! Either way if I first try apache2 and then apache1 I can't run both.

What is wrong?

I am using windows 7 with tomcat 7

Answer (score 1):

The default `CATALINA_HOME` is set in `catalina.bat` and it is relative to the location of the `bin` subdirectory.

So you can unzip a tomcat binary in `c:\tomcat1` and another in `c:\tomcat2`, and each will automatically have its own `CATALINA_HOME`.

As for the scenario you describe with a shared `CATALINA_HOME`, I see nothing that would prevent it from running ok. I would double and triple check that your `startup.bat` is calling the right instance, and each `server.xml` has the right ports configured.

Answer (score 0):

Recommended solution: Choose another port for your second tomcat instance to something other than 8081. 
Alternate solution: Change the port the McAfee FrameworkService.exe uses. [here](https://community.mcafee.com/message/17346) is a thread discussing options

I just ran into a similar issue when trying to run 2 tomcat instances on ports 8080 and 8081. Use `netstat -aon` as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5310945/deployment-errorstarting-of-tomcat-failed-the-server-port-8080-is-already-in-u) to see a list of open connections and associated process ids. Tracing this id, 1988 in my case, back to the process with `tasklist /FI "PID eq 1988"` showed that the McAfee FrameworkService.exe process was using 8081.