# TOMCAT - HTTP Status 404

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, http-status-code-404

I set up my server in eclipse and when I run it the console prints:

```
mai 02, 2013 4:05:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Application Virtualization Client;c:\Program Files (x86)\Open Text\View\bin;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\ThinkPad\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\ThinkPad\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\WorkspacePPL\apache-maven-3.0.4\bin;.
mai 02, 2013 4:05:13 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:ppl-webapp' did not find a matching property.
mai 02, 2013 4:05:13 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
mai 02, 2013 4:05:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 604 ms
mai 02, 2013 4:05:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
mai 02, 2013 4:05:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.36
mai 02, 2013 4:05:14 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
mai 02, 2013 4:05:14 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
mai 02, 2013 4:05:14 PM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/22  config=null
mai 02, 2013 4:05:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 493 ms
```

but then, if I browse `http://localhost:8080` I get:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /
---------------------------------------------------------------------
type Status report
message /
description The requested resource is not available.
```

While I should see the Tomcat welcome page.

If I run Tomcat outside of eclipse I can reach the welcome page.

Comment: Did you try Right click on server, properties , and clicked on Switch Location ?

Comment: WOW! Just did it and I got 5 SEVERE error messages!

Comment: What error messages ?

Comment: Check that wether you have your index.jsp/html file under your WebContent folder.

Answer (score 238, accepted):

1. Click on `Window > Show view > Server` or right click on the server in "Servers" view, select "Properties".
2. In the "General" panel, click on the "Switch Location" button.
3. The "Location: [workspace metadata]" should replace by something else.
4. Open the Overview screen for the server by double clicking it.
5. In the Server locations tab , select "Use Tomcat location".
6. Save the configurations and restart the Server.

You may want to follow the steps above before starting the server. Because server location section goes grayed-unreachable.

[image: server Locations in eclipse view]

Comment: What is this "Server Locations" used for? I always add my apps to <tomcat installed folder>/webapps. I want to know more about it.

Comment: @evan [This](https://github.com/opentripplanner/OpenTripPlanner/wiki/SettingUpATomcatServerInEclipse) may help you.

Comment: this didnt work, can you suggest any alternate solutions?

Comment: @NiteshVerma What do you get and what steps did you exactly followed after setting up your Tomcat under Eclipse IDE ?

Comment: i followed very common online tutorials to make a web service in java..

Comment: One step I suggest to add to answer is regarding removing the deployed projects and cleaning the server so that the `server locations` option is enabled as it is not enabled by default.

Comment: @NINCOMPOOP - worked like a charm for me! thanks. (my specs : Ubuntu 16.04, Tomcat 8 & Eclipse Neon)

Comment: it works but I am not sure why do we need to do this, can someone explain ?

Comment: Where exactly is this "server location" window ?

Answer (score 28):

To get your program to run, please put *jsp* files under web-content and not under `WEB-INF` because in Eclipse the files are not accessed there by the server, so try starting the server and browsing to URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/YourProject/yourfile.jsp
```

then your problem will be solved.

Comment: It's not about Eclipse, 'web-inf' is protected under Servlet specs .

Comment: this worked for me. thanks
In my case I was just trying to open a normal .jsp file

Comment: Nice piece of information. Can you share some link where I can read about things like this.

Comment: I was (unintentionally) adding index.html file to WEB-INF folder, hence my 3 configured servers, **Tomcat7, TomEE+ and JBoss** were unable to run that page. All displayed 404. index.html page and all other pages should be under `web-content` folder, not in `WEB-INF` folder. Thanks @Agrata

Answer (score 6):

You don't have to use Tomcat installation as a server location. It is much easier just to copy the files in the ROOT folder.

> Eclipse forgets to copy the default apps (ROOT, examples, etc.) when
>   it creates a Tomcat folder inside the Eclipse workspace. Go to
>   `C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.8\webapps`, R-click on the ROOT folder and copy
>   it. Then go to your Eclipse workspace, go to the `.metadata` folder, and
>   search for "wtpwebapps". You should find something like
>   `your-eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps`
>   (or `../tmp1/wtpwebapps` if you already had another server registered
>   in Eclipse). Go to the `wtpwebapps` folder, R-click, and paste ROOT (say
>   "yes" if asked if you want to merge/replace folders/files). Then
>   reload `http://localhost/` to see the Tomcat welcome page.

Source: [HTTP Status 404 error in tomcat](http://www.coderanch.com/forums/posts/list/40/87666)

Comment: the above still works in Eclipse Oxygen - I placed `docs examples ROOT` under `wtpwebapps` & `host-manager manager` under `webapps` directories (inside Eclipse `.metadata` directory as shown above)

Comment: if you use **Struts 2.5** , **tomcat** version **9.0** works, and no need to Switch Location, use 10.0 will get 404 error.