# HTTP Status 404 (The requested resource (/webApp/) is not available)

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, http-status-code-404

I am using `eclipse` and `tomcat 6`.

While running the project on server, getting the error.

I tried solving this by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8520267/localhost8080-gives-404-the-requested-resource-is-not-available) solution, and even [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16340711/tomcat-http-status-404).

Switched location

[image]

changed server location

[image]

Still no help, could anyone please suggest something.

Comment: Thanks @BalusC. I have solved this, but what shall I do with the question now. Can you close it or something?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what else could be done to solve this.

I run the `jsp` (whatever `index` file) file directly, and it is working.