# Eclipse maven web app - HTTP Status 500 and 404 errors

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, servlets

Although I am proficient in Java, I am completely new to developing web apps with maven and I am struggling to get started by creating a simple HelloWorld servlet app - I'm using Eclipse Mars and Tomcat 8.

I have added a simple servlet which should print out "hello world" but when I attempt to run the servlet by using the url-pattern (so `http://localhost:8080/MyApp/HelloWorld`) I get a 404 error.

When I ran the app for the very first time I got a 500 error stating that my servlet class could not be found but when I refreshed the page it changed to 404. Now I only get a 404 error. I have already tried the following but no joy - [TOMCAT - HTTP Status 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16340711/tomcat-http-status-404).

Any help would be much appreciated.

[image: Servlet class and web.xml]

Comment: Have you read Tomcat's startup log from top to bottom? Clues are usually found there (in Eclipse it's just there in *Console* tab). Warnings/Errors/Exceptions are usually quite googlable if not already self-explaining.

Comment: You have your java sources located in src/main/resources which is not the right place for this. Please create a directory src/main/java and put them there. This may remedy your problem.

Comment: Eureka! I have only spent the last 4 hours trying to fix this, I knew it would be something simple! Thanks for the help, you're a life saver!

Comment: Added the content as an answer.

Comment: That should have thrown a `ClassNotFoundException` on the servlet class in the server log which is in turn fairly self-explaining (the servlet class cannot be found). This in turn suggests you didn't bother to read the server log. In the future, do so. It's a source of clues.

Comment: Chill. It did throw a class not found exception as I have stated in my original post. I thought the problem was due to the file structure and location of my servlet which is why I included an image of the directory structure in my post. When you add a servlet in Eclipse, it puts them in a resources folder by default. I tried moving the servlet class around but I couldn't find an example of the correct way to structure the app on the net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your java sources located in `src/main/resources` which is not the right place for this. Please create a directory `src/main/java` and put them there. This should remedy your problem.