# Estado HTTP 404 – Not Found Eclipse/Tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, http-status-code-404

I'm new to this, and I'm lost.
My port is working, because if look up localhost:8080 Apache's shows in my screen, but when I do localhost:8080/"myproject"/"class" error 404 shows.

I only have one warning which is [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:"myproject"' did not find a matching property.

If it helps anyone, I'm trying to do a Connection Pool in java, so I had to type something in the web.xml and context.xml, but I did not touch those files from the Apache Foundation, they are all from my META-INF and WEB-INF

I followed this tutorial
[TOMCAT - HTTP Status 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16340711/tomcat-http-status-404)

I also did this
["SetPropertiesRule" warning message when starting Tomcat from Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104854/setpropertiesrule-warning-message-when-starting-tomcat-from-eclipse/106196)

I found this, but I don't get it
[Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:JSFTut' did not find a matching property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3566146/setting-property-source-to-org-eclipse-jst-jee-serverjsftut-did-not-find-a)

I searched for a solution but I couldn't find anything

Comment: Are you *literally* using those quotes around `"myproject"` etc? Or did you mean to emphasize these words in your question?

Comment: I'm not using the quotes...

Comment: You'll need to deploy your project to tomcat, under the name `myproject`. Also, as you say that you're editing some files: Please include code. Currently you're just stating *that* you changed something and it's impossible to tell you *what else* you'll have to change without seeing the code. Check [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You'd better not use quotes in your post, but show off the actual URL: `http://localhost:8080/example/like.this`.