# 404 NOT FOUND @Request Mapping to JSP in a Spring MVC app

Tags: xml, spring, jsp, jakarta-ee, model-view-controller

**The idea of this App is to show a JSP page when accessing the localhost:5060/project-name** .**Through the @RequestMapping annotation whenever I put the project name it should be redirected to the JSP file automatically which doesn't happen .**I'm using Tomcat 9 and localhost:5060 works fine.
. **The problem is that i couldn't access the jsp file as I get a 404 not found error** These are the config files .**1st this is web.xml**
 `

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

<display-name>spring-mvc-demo</display-name>

<!-- Spring MVC Configs -->

<!-- Step 1: Configure Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<!-- Step 2: Set up URL mapping for Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

`

**And this is Spring xml config file(spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <!-- Step 3: Add support for component scanning -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.springdemo.mvc" />

    <!-- Step 4: Add support for conversion, formatting and validation support -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <!-- Step 5: Define Spring MVC view resolver -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**The controller code below :**

```
package com.springdemo.mvc;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String showPage() {
        return "main-menu";
    }
}
```

THE JSP FILE BELOW

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>

<body>

<h2>Spring MVC Demo - Home Page</h2>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: have you tried this URL:   http://localhost:5060/

Comment: Yes it works fine , i get the apache interface..I changed the port to 5060 as I have glassfish for the 8080

Comment: Your url for jsp should be localhost:port/ , as / is what the route for jsp. Is you jsp name is the string you returned from Controller. main-menu.jsp

Comment: Yes it's named : main-menu.jsp and it's located inside the view folder under WEB-INF

Comment: I changed the tomcat to another version and copied the ROOT from tomcat to my eclipse workspace and it worked.
Solution is here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16340711/tomcat-http-status-404