# Resource Not Found?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

There's this dynamic web project (java) that I'm working on, which requires me to access the web-page it'll redirect me to. So usually when i start the server and run it from chrome, i go to the desired page. But since a couple of days, my project is misbehaving. The same URL which it earlier used to run properly, now shows

> Not Found : HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found"

After starting the tomcat server many times, on one run it randomly connects to the URL.

Does anyone know why this happens? And without any fix how am i able to reconnect to the URL again? And if you know, how to fix this issue?

Comment: Is the port available or is it already in use? Additionally check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731377/servlet-returns-http-status-404-the-requested-resource-servlet-is-not-availa) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11290029/http-status-404-on-eclipse-with-tomcat) answer as you haven't shared any code which makes it a very broad question.

Comment: @AdityaBhardwaj the ports are not in use. I'm running this project only. The thing is i haven't shared code because its too broad and i don't think its because of a faulty code. As said the page connects randomly, I've noticed i have to keep the tomcat server active for about 10-15 minutes before i can connect to the URL I wish to open in my project (localhost, that is). Hence I'm confused.