# Tomcat not starting (throwing java.net.BindException: )

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, web

I have done the following settings to run a Java web project but somehow my Tomcat is not starting from Eclipse:

```
JAVA_HOME : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_03  
PATH : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_03\bin  
CATALINA_HOME : D:\javaworkspaces\apache-tomcat-7.0.27
```

Then as is required, I set up a new server from Eclipse and give the Tomcat installation path.

As advised in some forums, I have added `tomcat-juli.jar` to the class path.
In spite of all this when I try starting the Tomcat Server, I get the the error as tomcat not staring in 45 sec.

I get the following log message:

```
Jul 26, 2012 5:49:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init  
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in     production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/lib/i386;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_03\bin;D:\eclipse-jee-indigo-SR2-win32\eclipse;;.  
Jul 26, 2012 5:49:34 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule   
 begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property         'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:JEE_Day01' did not find a matching property.  
Jul 26, 2012 5:49:34 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init  
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-80"]  
Jul 26, 2012 5:49:35 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init  
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]  
Jul 26, 2012 5:49:35 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init  
SEVERE: Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]  
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind <null>:8009  
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:393)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:566)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:417)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:956)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:559)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:814)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:624)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:649)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:281)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:449)  
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(Unknown Source)
at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultServerSocketFactory.java:49)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:380)
... 16 more  
Jul 26, 2012 5:49:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService initInternal    
    SEVERE: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[AJP/1.3-8009]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[AJP/1.3-8009]]  
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106)  
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:559)  
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:814)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:624)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:649)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:281)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:449)  
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:958)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
... 12 more
```

I have referred multiple forums but am badly stuck with the situation. Please guide me.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

these lines :

```
SEVERE: Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind <null>:8009
```

imply that there is already a service running on port 8009. is there a tomcat (with ajp) running already?

if the service running on 8009 is needed you could change the connector configuration in server.xml to something like below :

```
<Connector port="8089" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
```

Answer (score 10):

It says the port number `8009`  is already occupied by some other process running on your OS [try searching for that process and stop it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5310945/deployment-errorstarting-of-tomcat-failed-the-server-port-8080-is-already-in-u) or make your tomcat to run on different (free) port

Answer (score 7):

kill the respective (listening) process on this port i.e. 8009.
use

> `netstat -a -o -n`

to look for the PID of the process. It may look something like this
TCP    [::]:8009              [::]:0                 LISTENING       892

use the taskkill command to kill the process.
example:

> `taskkill /F /PID 892`

Comment: to kill the process, you may need admin rights. To do so, look for "cmd" in Windows start search box, right-click on "cmd.exe" and choose "open as administrator"

Answer (score 5):

> java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind :8009

This means that some other process is already using this port. Could it be another Tomcat instance?

Answer (score 2):

**You should not have to change the server.port to fix this problem...**

*Mac/Unix/Linux Users*: If after you restart Tomcat, and this problem still exists, it is probably because Tomcat was shutdown improperly and there are resources still associated with it that are now locked.
You can see the PIDs of those resources by running this command:

```
lsof | grep tomcat
```

Terminate those processes using:

```
kill -15 <PID>
```

This should fix your problem.

> Using the **kill -15** command to TERM (-15) the process rather than SIGKILL (-9) is preferable. The -15 switch sends the process the signal to begin it's shutdown phases and clean up bounded resources.

Answer (score 0):

Try :http://localhost:8089
if it is not worked (or)
Try this: Set:JRE_HOME : C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.5.0_11 (depend on your version of JRE) and add the C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.5.0_11 (depend on your version of JRE)\bin to path
Eclipse-> go to windows preferences:server->RuntimeEnvironment remove added Server and Referesh and add new TomcatServer

Answer (score 0):

TIL: Someone else on a server can start IIS on port 80 and not tell anyone.
If you have your tomcat configured for the same port, it will also report this error.
The port on IIS or tomcat will need to be changed.

To modify the port in IIS:
Administrative Tools | Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager
Right Click on Default Web Site | Edit Bindings...
Change Port

-OR-

To modify the port in Tomcat:
Open conf\server.xml and update the port value in tag:

```
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
    connectionTimeout="20000"
    redirectPort="8443"
    URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

Restart Tomcat

Enjoy 2 web services.

Answer (score 0):

Something else is using port 8009.

Either shut down the thing that is using 8009 or change your server.xml to use another port than 8009

Answer (score 0):

This generally happens if the Connector / shutdown port of the tomcat is already being used. 
First, run the shutdown.bat (Sometimes we miss out that one instance of the tomcat is already running)
Next, in the command prompt run

```
netstat -aon | findstr 0.0:<your port number which is giving bind exception>
```

To get the PID of the application that is currently using your port. Either kill that application or use some other port which is not listed when you run

```
netstat -a -o -n
```

Answer (score 0):

Update all available ports one by one with ports that are free. This must fix the issue

31-Jul-2019 16:28:30.641 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await StandardServer.await: create[localhost:**8005**]: 
    java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind

Answer (score 0):

Other Tomcat is running on the same port so better to kill using 9 rather than 15

kill -9 PID

This was helpful to me.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution! However, as @cosbor11 wrote, in this case it is better to kill using `TERM` first and wait a bit. This gives tomcat time to shutdown gracefully and free its resources. Only if nothing happens for a while, you may kill using `SIGKILL`. You also may want to try the command `pkill`. It allows you to kill all processes matching a certain name, so you don't need a PID.