# Grails: Resolving "Server failed to start for port 8080: Address already in use."

Tags: grails

I'm getting this error when trying to resolve "`Server failed to start for port 8080: Address already in use`"

```
 Error executing script 8888: For input string: ""
```

Can anybody help? Don't know what's wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 26):

When the port number 8080 is already used  and you want to reuse the same port , you should kill its process :

First, check the pid of the process that is using port 8080. To do this run:

```
lsof -w -n -i tcp:8080
```

[image: Result after running Command]

In the example above, the pid is 3812 for process that is using port 9090

Take note of the PID. The PID could be different on your machine. We need this for executing the next command: 
[image: kill process]

so you will have to test it via run-app:

```
grails run-app
```

UPDATE :
As the output of `lsof -w -n -i tcp:8080| awk '{print $2}'|awk 'END{print}'` is the PID
, You can kill the port process by PID automatically :

```
 kill -9 `lsof -w -n -i tcp:8080| awk '{print $2}'|awk 'END{print}'`
```

Comment: Your method of killing the process can be compacted to `kill -9 \`lsof -t -i tcp:8080\``

Comment: On windows, the command to get the pid of the process that is using port 8080 is `netstat -a -n -o | find "8080"`

Answer (score 8):

If you're using **Grails/Groovy Tool Suite** ( Eclipse based IDE ), select **Run as > Run Configurations....**
Then, in Grails tab, input like this :

```
-Dserver.port=8050 run-app
```

So, Grails will run on port 8050 instead of the default port (8080).

Answer (score 4):

The message

> Server failed to start for port 8080: Address already in use

indicates that some other process on your machine has already bound itself to port 8080. I would guess this is an instance of Tomcat running either because you started it or it didn't get properly shutdown by whatever IDE you use.

In any case, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5310945/deployment-errorstarting-of-tomcat-failed-the-server-port-8080-is-already-in-u) should help you end the process that is using the port.

As for the second error regarding script 8888, I have no idea. Grails does not attempt to start this script in my environment, so I imagine it is related to a plugin you have installed.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the port number 8080 is already used. So, you either have to stop that process to make way for the new one or you can specify `grails -Dserver.port=8090 run-app` when you run your app.

However, since you're having a script error, it is possible that you didn't specify the port in your BuildConfig.groovy.

here's the solution:
add `grails.server.port.http=8888` in your `BuildConfig.groovy`

refer to a comment here: 
http://www.icodeya.com/2012/06/grails-resolving-server-failed-to-start.html

Answer (score 2):

HOW TO KILL A BUSY PORT

open command prompt and type in C:>netstat -a -n -o | find "8080"
find the PID of the port example
 TCP    0.0.0.0:8888           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       9068

next

C:>taskkill /PID 9068 /F
SUCCESS: The process with PID 9068 has been terminated.

Answer (score 1):

If  you are using STS or Eclipse (or probably any environment built on Eclipse), one option is to go to the Debug perspective (**Window -> Open perspective -> Debug**). From there you can right click on your running server and click **Terminate and relaunch**. This will kill the current server and relaunch on the same port so that you do not get the `Server failed to start for port 8080: Address already in use` message.

As for the `Error executing script 8888: For input string: ""` I have not seen it before but it seems @ShootingStar has an answer.

Answer (score 1):

When the port number 8080 is already used and you want to reuse the same port , you should kill its process :
Use `fuser 8080/tcp` will print you PID of process bound on that port.

And this `fuser -k 8080/tcp` will kill that process.

Woks on Linux only. More universal is use of `lsof -i4` (or 6 for IPv6).

EXAMPLE: if the port is 8080,Run on terminal  :

```
 fuser -k -n tcp 8080
```

That is it!

Answer (score 1):

It means that there is a service using the port 8080. 
You can type on the terminal the command "netstat" to verify it.

How to stop a service using this port?
On windows you can stop such service with these steps:

1. Lon on to your system as Administrator
2. From the START menu, select CONTROL PANEL, then ADMINISTRATIVE TOOLS, then SERVICES.
3. From the list, find a service with a name ending in: Web Server and stop it.

If it is not running as a service, you may need to use the Task Manager to force it to stop.

Answer (score 0):

Easier than other posted answers.

In the console window there is a X and XX icon.  When you hover the cursor over it. You'll see balloons showing "Remove Launch" and  "Remove All Terminated Launches".

Click them both.  Eclipse will clear out all the existing servers so you can relaunch you server on the your default port.

Answer (score 0):

You need to kill the process which is running on port 8080;
So use the command:

```
netstat -plten |grep java
```

used grep java as tomcat uses java as their processes.

It will show the list of processes with port number and process id

```
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      
1000       30070621    16085/java
```

the number before /java is a process id. Now use kill command to kill the process

```
kill -9 16085
```

-9 implies the process will be killed forcefully.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the 8080 port is using currently.

```
sudo lsof -i :8080
```

Then you can see the port status including `COMMAND`, `PID`, `USER` and something like that.

Then, You can terminate it with the `PID`.

```
kill -9 <PID>
```