# Other instance of server on port 8080

Tags: eclipse, macos, grails, ports

I am a Mac noob here.

When I try to run my Grails project I get:

```
 Error Server failed to start for port 8080: Address already in use (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

On Windows, I would have just done `netstat -aon`  and killed the process on 8080.

On a Mac, I’m new, so I haven’t much of a clue. I tried:

```
lsof -i | grep 8080
```

and couldn’t see anything on port 8080.

So I tried just:

```
lsof -i
```

and I still couldn’t see anything on 8080.

Any tips?

Comment: without -P your ports are alisased to names, try `lsof -i -P | grep 8080`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly a case for moving to superuser, but "lsof -i :8080" will exactly show what's listening on that port.

Answer (score 0):

As per my answer at [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13522307/grails-resolving-server-failed-to-start-for-port-8080-address-already-in-use/22785090#22785090).  This is easier than @nitind's answer.

In the console window there is a X and XX icon. When you hover the cursor over it. You'll see balloons showing "Remove Launch" and "Remove All Terminated Launches".

Click them both. Eclipse will clear out all the existing servers so you can relaunch you server on the your default port.