# starting grails gives me: `Server failed to start for port 8080: Address already in use: JVM_Bind`

Tags: grails, groovy

I am using groovy and grails tool suite( `ggts` ), when run grail application the following error fire:

```
Server failed to start for port 8080: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
                                      (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

so guide me on this situation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grails: Resolving "Server failed to start for port 8080: Address already in use."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13522307/grails-resolving-server-failed-to-start-for-port-8080-address-already-in-use)

Comment: in 8080 port, some other application is running. kill that first. otherwise try to restart the system

Answer (score 2):

You have to stop other app listening 8080 port, or use a different port. Like 8081:

```
grails -Dserver.port=8081 run-app
```

Also you could configure Grails to always use 8081 port by adding into `grails-app/conf/Config.groovy` following line:

```
grails.server.port.http=8081
```