# A Grails run-app Error

Tags: grails, plugins, grails-plugin

When I typed the command `grails run-app` into my terminal, I got this error message:

> Error Server failed to start for port 8080: Address already in use
>   (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)

How do I get my application to launch?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grails: Resolving "Server failed to start for port 8080: Address already in use."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13522307/grails-resolving-server-failed-to-start-for-port-8080-address-already-in-use)

Answer (score 2):

That would indicate you already have something running on port `8080`. If you want to run your application on another port you can use the following command:

```
grails run-app -Dserver.port=8090
```

The above will run your application on port `8090`.

Comment: Or find out, what is already using that port by typing `lsof -i:8080` and kill that.