# how can i resolve java.net.BindException adress already in use : bind

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot, port

...and The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8080 failed to start

im also using TCPview, so witch process should i stop in the picture

[image]

whats more, im working under spring-boot so i cant configure the port

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tomcat: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM\_Bind <null>:80](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25742913/tomcat-java-net-bindexception-address-already-in-use-jvm-bind-null80)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> so which process should i stop

The process with ID 6076

> im working under spring-boot so i cant configure the port

Using Spring Boot doesn't stop you from configuring the port. If you are using an embedded container you can set the `server.port` property. If you are deploying a war to a standalone container then you can use the container's standard mechanism for configuring the port on which it listens.