# Having issue with Tomcat when I run in a eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I am novice in java I have installed Tomcat and it runs fine in a browser but when I run in a eclipse its showing error like

> Several ports (8005, 8282, 8009) required by Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost are already in use. The server may already be running in another process, or a system process may be using the port. To start this server you will need to stop the other process or change the port number(s).

I would like to mention one thing I am not authorized to login with admin account I have tried lot to stop the already running stuff through command prompt and i followed this link [Deployment error: Starting of tomcat fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5310945/deployment-errorstarting-of-tomcat-failed-the-server-port-8080-is-already-in-u/5310993#5310993)
however I am getting the same error is there any way to solve this issue.
Thank You.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Several ports (8005, 8080, 8009) required by Tomcat Server at localhost are already in use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064733/several-ports-8005-8080-8009-required-by-tomcat-server-at-localhost-are-alre)

Answer (score -1):

Some other process is using one or more of the ports needed by tomcat (8005, 8282, 8009). Probably an old instance of tomcat. Kill it, then try again.

You can run `netstat -abn` on windows or `netstat -apn` on Linux to figure out which process is listening to these ports.

Comment: hi, I followed your command but I am getting this message after execution which is- "The requested operation requires elevation"

Comment: To run netstat with these switches on windows you need an admin command prompt. Click start, type CMD, right click on CMD, and choose 'Run as administrator'