# Starting of Tomcat failed, the shutdown port 8005 is already in use

Tags: tomcat, port

```
ant -f C:\\Users\\authentic\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\WebApplication3 -Dnb.internal.action.name=run -Ddirectory.deployment.supported=true -DforceRedeploy=false -Dnb.wait.for.caches=true -Dbrowser.context=C:\\Users\\authentic\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\WebApplication3 run
init:
deps-module-jar:
deps-ear-jar:
deps-jar:
library-inclusion-in-archive:
library-inclusion-in-manifest:
compile:
compile-jsps:
Starting of Tomcat failed, the shutdown port 8005 is already in use.
C:\Users\authentic\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WebApplication3\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1045: Deployment error: Starting of Tomcat failed, the shutdown port 8005 is already in use.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 seconds)
```

[image]

when i change tomcat port am getting this error "Starting of Tomcat failed, the shutdown port 8005 is already in use."

Comment: Have you tried searching server.xml, the File that you're showing here,  for 8005?

Comment: It is probable that some process is stuck. See this question for how to kill it. [Deployment error:Starting of Tomcat failed, the server port 8080 is already in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5310945/deployment-errorstarting-of-tomcat-failed-the-server-port-8080-is-already-in-u)

Comment: I had my shutdown port the same as my service port.  So when it was complaining about being in use, it was... itself.

Answer (score 5):

Change the shutdown  port number to maybe 8006 or 8004. Worked for me
Cange it at NetBeans at tools->servers->shutdown port

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53546469/edit) your answer if you want to add information, do not repost answers.